# Chord or tabs sheet for Baden's time

Tags: theory, sheet-music, musicology

Can anyone please tell me the chords or tabs for baden's song to play on Acoustic guitar ?
I wanna play it so badly pls help me .
song : Baden's time (https://open.spotify.com/track/1yQs0zVm0oNXKRfp4sAOvU?si=O8XTvm2KTR2uMYKC0V0nZg)

Comment: Sorry but requesting transcriptions is not done here. Maybe you’ll have some luck here: https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=120 Many TAB request sites are paid but this one seems like it’s free.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy thx a lot for the link ,it really help me a lot